# Why django-registration using the wrong path for own files?

Tags: django, django-registration

I installed django-registration and copied 'registratioт' folder to the project as it should be. For a long time I could not understand why changes in forms.py have no effect on the result pages are displayed. And found that django-registration using the files not from

> \Project\ registration

folder but from

> \python\Lib\site-packages\django_registration_redux-1.1-py2.7.egg\registration

How to point the right path for the application?

I use django 1.6 and django-registration https://github.com/macropin/django-registration

Comment: Why would you copy the registration folder to the project? That's certainly not "as it should be".

Comment: Because the application must be in the project folder. Is not it? Well, I have little knowledge in this. But earlier (when it was Jango version 1.5) project worked correctly when the registration was in the project folder. What has changed?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. You've installed the app - since it's in the site-packages folder - so your project can use it there.